# Why it is successed that I use str(unicode) in Django?

Tags: django

As I know, I can't use str(unicode) directly， especially the unicode string contains Chinese. But it is successed that I use str(u'中文') in Django. And ‘中文’ is Chinese. How magical it is! I am wonder why it can succeed. Who can tell me?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Django replaces the standard `str()` function with something more useful in this context.

It's probably replaced by `smart_str()` ([see the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/)) which automatically creates UTF-8.